# Get date of Monday two weeks ago from particular date using GNU date

Tags: linux, date

I understand the command `date -d 'last-monday - 14 days' +%Y%m%d` will print the Monday two weeks ago from "Today's date". I need a way to test this for different dates and see the result. Almost like I need to mention the date command to do calculations off a relative date.

I need something to test with different dateslike :

```
date -d 'last-monday - 14 days' %Y%m%d from 20190315

date -d 'last-monday - 14 days' %Y%m%d from 20180217

date -d 'last-monday - 14 days' %Y%m%d from 201700914
```

and see the respective outputs.

Comment: You'd want a way to get (respectively to your example) results such as: ```20190225``` and ```20180129``` and ```20170828```, am I correct ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Our given dates
dates=(
    20190315
    20180217
    20170914
)

# Loop over the given dates
for thedate in "${dates[@]}"; do
    # Get day of the week as digit (1 is Monday, 7 is Sunday)
    day=$( date -d "$thedate" +%u )
    # The Monday the same week is $(( day - 1 )) days earlier than the given date.
    # The Monday two weeks earlier is 14 days earlier still.

    date -d "$thedate -$(( day - 1 + 14 )) days" +"$thedate --> %Y%m%d"
done
```

Output:

```
20190315 --> 20190225
20180217 --> 20180129
20170914 --> 20170828
```

The difficult bit about this is to figure out how to construct the correct `--date` or `-d` string for GNU `date` to compute the final date.  I opted for computing the day of week of the given date, and then using that to compute a date string that offsets the given date by a number of days so that the resulting date is the Monday two weeks earlier.

The actual strings that ends up being used for the option argument to `-d` in the above script, using the dates given in the script, are

```
20190315 -18 days
20180217 -19 days
20170914 -17 days
```

Condensing the script into a single command that does the computation for a single date in `$thedate`:

```
date -d "$thedate -$(date -d "$thedate" +%u) days -13 days" +%Y%m%d
```

or

```
date -d "$thedate -$(date -d "$thedate" +"-%u days -13 days")" +%Y%m%d
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ date
Wed Mar 20 15:02:23 MST 2019
$ date -d "last-monday"
Mon Mar 18 00:00:00 MST 2019
$ date -d "last-monday - 1 week"
Mon Mar 11 00:00:00 MST 2019
```

Comment: The issue seems to be finding the date of the Monday two weeks before a _particular_ date.

Comment: Not an answer to the original question, but definitely what I was looking for. Useful to know the date-command can do maths like this.

Answer (score 5):

On at least Debian there is a `faketime` package

```
faketime '2019-03-15' date
Fri 15 Mar 00:00:00 GMT 2019

faketime '2019-03-15' date --date 'last monday - 14 days'
Mon 25 Feb 00:00:00 GMT 2019
```

Answer (score 0):

The overkill solution:

Create a bare-bones virtual machine. 
Run it in single user mode,
so no background services are running. 
Just to be sure, double-check that NTP is not running.

Then set the date to whatever you want to set it to,
and do your tests.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to take a "reusable tool" approach.

My `monday` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
date=${1:-now}
shift
dow=`date +%u -d "$date"`
dow0=$[ $dow - 1 ]
date -d "$date -$dow0 days" "$@"
```

How it works:

- get `date -d` argument from first command line argument, e.g. "2020-01-01 -2 weeks"
- additional args are passed on to the final date command, e.g. to format with `+%F`
- get the day of week with %u (1..7); 1 is Monday
- subtract 1 as we want the range 0 to 6.
- show the date for the given date, minus the "day of the week" offset

A similar `sunday` script, which turns out to be a little simpler:

```
#!/bin/bash
date=${1:-now}
shift
dow=`date +%w -d "$date"`
date -d "$date -$dow days" "$@"
```

Usage:

```
# monday 
Mon Aug 29 02:28:45 PM AEST 2022
# sunday now +%F
2022-08-28
# monday '2022-12-01' +%F
2022-11-28
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `date` command's `-s`/`--set` option:

```
# date
Wed Mar 20 23:02:18 CET 2019
# date -s '20190315' > /dev/null; date -d 'last-monday - 14 days'
Mon Feb 25 00:00:00 CET 2019
```

Depending on your system, you might have to prefix with `sudo` or reset afterwards via `ntpdate`

Comment: Setting the system's clock seems like overkill just to get the correct output. It may also confuse certain services and scheduled tasks, and other users of the system if it's a multi-user system.

Comment: @Kusalananda I agree, in principle, but most modern systems will automatically resync via ntp anyway. When I tested this, date returned the correct time immediately afterwards; hence the `;` instead of using two separate commands to show what I'm doing.
But if you really don't want to touch your system time, there does exist a `faketime` package.

Comment: The `ntpd` daemon won't resync if you exceed its the 300 second variance.

Comment: Then there is something else going on in my system (Mint 19), because 5d > 300s  and as I said: running above command didn't affect anything beyond the commands in the current line.

In fact:
`# date -s '19700102' ; date ; sleep 1 ; date` yields
    `Fri Jan  2 00:00:00 CET 1970`
    `Fri Jan  2 00:00:00 CET 1970`
    `Wed Mar 20 23:49:26 CET 2019`

Comment: Maybe you're running `ntpdate` from `cron` (ugh), or perhaps `chrony` has a larger leeway. Or there again there's whatever the `systemd` borg has done to NTP.

Comment: Since there is no such thing as `cron.secondly` or an equivalent of that in crontab and a leeway that reaches back to epoch +0 seems silly, I guess it's the latter.